# Rows That Are Included/Contained In a String

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a "Pandas Data Frame":

There is a bunch of Q&A that explains how to select rows that contain a given substring.

But I'm curious about finding how to split rows that are substring of a given string.

Unfortunately my datas are huge but suppose we have a column that its entries are single words.

For a given sentence we should return corresponding rows that have words of given sentence. For simple example:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'Words': ['I', 'have', 'a', 'Pandas', 'Data', 'Frame']})`

And the given sentence is:

`s = 'You have one Pandas array Frame'`

Now I need some thing like this:

`df_s = df[df['Words'] in s]`

That means:

`df_s = pd.DataFrame({'Words': ['have', 'Pandas', 'Frame']})`

Comment: Please share sample input and expected output.

Comment: @MayankPorwal My examples are bigger than I can include them  right here :( But I try to explain more explicitly what I need to learn.

Comment: *rows that are included in a longer string*... I may be stupid, but I cannot imagine what you mean here...

Comment: *My examples are bigger than I can include them right here*. No. What we ask here is just a small number of rows and columns, only enough to reproduce the problem. Do not forget that English is not the first language for a number of users here, but sample data is an universal language that everybody can understand...

Comment: @SergeBallesta I add some codes that show what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply` can be used to apply one function to all the rows (resp. columns) of a dataframe. It should not be used without caution, because as soon as you apply a Python function you lose the vectorization and performances fall down. Yet it is an appropriate tool here.

`df['Words'] in s` should be written: `df['Words'].apply(lambda x: x in s)`, and you end with:

```
print(df[df['Words'].apply(lambda x: x in s)])
    Words
1    have
2       a
3  Pandas
5   Frame
```

Here we have kept the `'a'`, because it is indeed a substring of `s`. I you want to keep words, you should use `split` and compare full words:

```
s = 'You have one Pandas array Frame'.split()
```

It now gives the expected:

```
    Words
1    have
3  Pandas
5   Frame
```